# How to use Proximity Alerts to trigger a Notification?

Tags: android

Is it possible?
I mean when I get close some specific place,I get a Notification.
Proximity Alerts will fire a Intent,but I don't know how to start a Notification with a Intent.
Someting like Intent(String action) and IntentFilter?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1): Set up your proximity alert.

From the [LocationManager doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

> ```
> public void  addProximityAlert  (double latitude, double longitude,float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent  intent)
> ```

Define an action and set it in your `PendingIntent`.

Step 2): Define in the `AndroidManifest.xml` your broadcastreceiver with the same action set in your proximity alert.
In the `onReceive` method of the BroadcastReceiver, display your notification

When you will be in the zone that you have define with `latitude`, `longitude` and `radius`,
the `PendingIntent` will be fired and will be received and processed by your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a BroadcastReceiver. In the manifest, you can specify the Intents to be filtered by the receiver. In the BroadcastReceiver's "onReceive" method is where you can write the code to show your notification.

Comment: I "have to" use BroadcastReceiver?Well,I made a NotificationAdapter(well,my Eng is poor,so this may be a funny name to you),and put every details in the constructor,so new NotificationAdapter() will trigger a Notification.Now I should put this in a customized BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: BroadcastReceivers are the listeners of the Intents. It's just listening to your Intent to be disptached, you can use the handler "onReceive" method to do whatever you want, for example create one NotificationAdapter object of yours.
I'm not really sure if you can set an Intent listener without BroadcastReceivers, but I think that is the proper way to do it. You may want to have a look to the "Application Fundamentals" article, at Android's developers website.